# If I'm voluntarily VAT registered, but under the threshold, do I have to charge vat?

Tags: united-kingdom, vat

Suppose I'm voluntarily VAT registered in the UK. But my turnover is less than £85k. Do I have to charge my customers VAT on my products and services?

Put another way, in such circumstances am I only required to charge VAT at the point when I exceed the £85k threshold ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are VAT registered you have to charge VAT at the relevant rate on applicable goods and services, and pay it over to HMRC, irrespective of whether you are under or over the threshold.

If your turnover is under the threshold, you can de-register, but will have to charge VAT until they process the de-registration.  See more at https://www.gov.uk/vat-registration/cancel-registration